npm tries to install other version of node than selected by nvm
I have an issue with npm. It tries to install node version 14.21.3 which i was using before for other projects even though I choose version 20.17 using command nvm use 20.17.
I uninstalled npm and node with clearing all the modules. I cleared all versions from .nvm/versions/node/v20.17.0/bin/node
Here is screen with error message.

npm does not in any way "try to install node verison x.y.z". Did you read the error message? The npm version you try is to new for the node.js version you use.

I choose version 20.17 via nvm using nvm install 20.17, nvm switches npm version to be compatible with node version I choosed but even doing so when writing npm install it tries to install 14.21.3 for some reason

It seems you have an old version of node on your system, which wasn't installed by nvm (but probably the package manager if your system). And this version seems to be the first one to be found in your path.
Use which node to find the respective executable and try to get rid of this version. As you seem to be on Ubuntu you could try
sudo apt remove nodejs npm

Which should remove a nodejs/npm installed by apt. If that doesn't uninstall anything, you have to investigate further where the old node version comes from

Globaly i use node 22.9. I deleted node and npm and cleared all node modules and then reinstalled node and npm. Didn`t help.

What happens if you do which node and node --version ? Did you install node 14 via nvm? By any chance you have an .nvmrc in that project (which will override the global nvm config)

Yes i installed node 14 by nvm. Globaly i use 22.9. When i do which node 14.21.3 in .nvm/version/node doesnt apear on the list since i removed it before trying to fix it. When using nvm ls 14 version doesnt apear here either cause it got un-installed aswell.

And no, I don't have .nvmrc in that project

So when nvm's node 14 show's up when you do which node but doesn't when you do nvm ls there is something broken with your nvm environment and I'd suggest to remove all traces of nvm from your machine (see for instance on how to do so https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/298) and do a fresh install

Node 14 doesn't show up when using which node and doesn't show up when using nvm ls because I un-installed all instances of this version but when I do npm install it tries to install node 14

Sorry, misread your comment about the results of which node.  But still, it doesn't try to install anything The error you are seeing, tells you then while running, npm@10  finds itself in an environment of node@14 (wherever that comes from) which isn't compatible. I'd still suggest to remove any traces of node, npm and nvm from your machine (ie really delete them from your disk, not just do nvm uninstall)  and do a fresh install
